# Clear all Rectangles off map in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently working on a program in which a user would be able to highlight grid squares on a map. Currently, my code creates a Rectangle the size of a grid square in the location of the click. I also want to make a button that would clear all of the Rectangles. I attempted to add each new Rectangle into a global array, and then have each of the items in the array cleared when the clear rectangles button is pressed, but this is not working.

Simplified code:

```
var map;                //google map
var llOffset;           //size of grid squares (in degrees)

var countryOff = 1.6;
var countryZoom = 4;

var gridSquares = [];

var infoWindow;

function ZoomControl(controlDiv, map) {
    var control = this;

    //set CSS for the control border
    var countryZoomUI = document.createElement('div');
    countryZoomUI.id = 'countryZoomUI';
    countryZoomUI.title = 'Click to go to clear squares';
    controlDiv.appendChild(countryZoomUI);
    //set CSS for the control interior
    var countryZoomText = document.createElement('div');
    countryZoomText.id = 'countryZoomText';
    countryZoomText.innerHTML = 'Clear Squares';
    countryZoomUI.appendChild(countryZoomText);

    // Setup the click event listeners: set zoom level to country level.
    countryZoomUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
        clearSquares();
        setllOffset(countryOff);
        map.setZoom(countryZoom);
    });
}

//GOOGLE MAP INITILIZE
function initMap() {

    var markers = [];
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 33.00, lng: -100.00},
      zoom: 4,
      scaleControl: true
    });
    setllOffset(countryOff);

    // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the CenterControl()
    // constructor passing in this DIV.
    var zoomControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var zoomControl = new ZoomControl(zoomControlDiv, map);

    zoomControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(zoomControlDiv);


    //on click, create filled in rectangle
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        createGridBox(event.latLng);
    });
    DrawGridOn();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function DrawGridOn() {
    drawGridBox = true;
}

function DrawGridOff() {
    drawGridBox = false;
}

function setllOffset(offset){
    llOffset = offset;
}

function clearSquares(){
    for (var i=0; i< gridSquares.length; i++) {
        gridSquares[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

/**
Create filled in rectangle in grid (when clicked)
**/
function createGridBox(point) {

var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#0000FF',
      fillOpacity: 0.25,
      map: map,
      bounds: {
        north: Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset + llOffset,
        south: Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset,
        east: Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset + llOffset,
        west: Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset
      }
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function( event ){
    rectangle.setMap(null); 
});

gridSquares.push(rectangle);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it quite works like that. I was under the impression that you have to loop through your array and set all of the rectangles map properties equal to 'null'. You can then throw them out by clearing the array, but you first have to do this. At least that's what I thought.

Comment: The posted code "works" for me.  What do you mean when you say it "is not working"? ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d54q2sxo/))  What errors do you get in the javascript console?

Comment: Very weird, it works on jsfiddle but not my machine. What didn't work was that clicking the button did not do anything - in my code the button would also change the zoom of the map, which worked until I tried to add the rectangle clearing.